# smulwb assembly instruction

Tags: objective-c, c, assembly, arm, inline-assembly

I'm trying to understand this code:

```
inline SInt32 smul32by16(SInt32 i32, SInt16 i16)
{
    register SInt32 r;
    asm volatile("smulwb %0, %1, %2" : "=r"(r) : "r"(i32), "r"(i16));
    return r;
}
```

Does anybody know what this assembly instruction does?

**Update:**
P.S. I use objective C. and I should understand some code from assembly. That's why it's difficult for me to understand this code.

Comment: Please, see my update. I really don't even know, what is ARM. I just analize Apple sample code. I don't have knowledge in assembly.

Comment: I ask about the command inside. "smulwb %0, %1, %2" : "=r"(r) : "r"(i32), "r"(i16)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It does signed 32 bit by signed 16 bit multiplication and returns the top 32 bit of 48 bit result. The b specifies to use the bottom 16bit of the third operand.

So, translating it into pseudo code:

```
int_48 temp;
temp = i32*i16;
result = temp >> 16;
```

Answer (score 3):

See here for the description of the ARM SMUL and SMULW instructions:

http://infocenter.arm.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.arm.doc.dui0553a/CHDIABBH.html

Answer (score 3):

by using `asm` you can give assembler commands.

and using `volatile` for the reason,

```
volatile for the asm construct,  to prevent GCC from deleting the asm statement as unused
```

see this [link](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Extended-Asm.html) for better understanding

command inside ask instruction means :

```
SMULWB       R4, R5, R3       ; Multiplies R5 with the bottom halfword of R3,
                              ; extracts top 32 bits and writes to R4.
```

Comment: No, I ask only about the command "smulwb %0, %1, %2" : "=r"(r) : "r"(i32), "r"(i16)